# Android Frequency vs Amplitude real time using FFT

Tags: java, android, fft, processing, audio-recording

I am still newbie in android and FFT. I want to make an android app like Frequency Analyzer. Which have frequency and amplitude in the vertical side.
I try this code from http://therandomlab.blogspot.com/2013/05/fft-audio-frequency-analysis-with.html

I'm using Processing.

```
import processing.core.*;
import processing.data.*;
import processing.event.*;
import processing.opengl.*;

import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class android_fft_minim extends PApplet {

    int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 44100;
    int MAX_FREQ = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE / 2;
    final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
    final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    final int PEAK_THRESH = 20;

    short[] buffer = null;
    int bufferReadResult = 0;
    AudioRecord audioRecord = null;
    boolean aRecStarted = false;
    int bufferSize = 2048;
    int minBufferSize = 0;
    float volume = 0;
    FFT fft = null;
    float[] fftRealArray = null;
    int mainFreq = 0;

    float drawScaleH = (float) 1.5; // TODO: calculate the drawing scales
    float drawScaleW = (float) 1.0; // TODO: calculate the drawing scales
    int drawStepW = 2; // display only every Nth freq value
    float maxFreqToDraw = 2500; // max frequency to represent graphically
    int drawBaseLine = 0;

    public void setup() {
        //Toast.makeText(android_fft_minim.this, "lalag", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        drawBaseLine = displayHeight - 150;
        minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
                RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);

        // if we are working with the android emulator, getMinBufferSize() does
        // not work
        // and the only samplig rate we can use is 8000Hz
        if (minBufferSize == AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
            RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 8000; // forced by the android emulator
            MAX_FREQ = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE / 2;
            bufferSize = 2 << (int) (log(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE) / log(2) - 1);// buffer
                                                                            // size
                                                                            // must
                                                                            // be
                                                                            // power
                                                                            // of
                                                                            // 2!!!
            // the buffer size determines the analysis frequency at:
            // RECORDER_SAMPLERATE/bufferSize
            // this might make trouble if there is not enough computation power
            // to record and analyze
            // a frequency. In the other hand, if the buffer size is too small
            // AudioRecord will not initialize
        } else
            bufferSize = minBufferSize;
        buffer = new short[bufferSize];
        // use the mic with Auto Gain Control turned off!


            audioRecord = new AudioRecord(
                    MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION,
                    RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
                    RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);




        // audioRecord = new AudioRecord( MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
        // RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
        // RECORDER_CHANNELS,RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);
        if ((audioRecord != null)
                && (audioRecord.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)) {
            try {
                // this throws an exception with some combinations
                // of RECORDER_SAMPLERATE and bufferSize
                try {
                    audioRecord.startRecording();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(android_fft_minim.this, "error recording", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                aRecStarted = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                aRecStarted = false;
            }

            if (aRecStarted) {
                bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                // verify that is power of two
                if (bufferReadResult % 2 != 0)
                    bufferReadResult = 2 << (int) (log(bufferReadResult) / log(2));

                fft = new FFT(bufferReadResult, RECORDER_SAMPLERATE);
                fftRealArray = new float[bufferReadResult];
                drawScaleW = drawScaleW * (float) displayWidth
                        / (float) fft.freqToIndex(maxFreqToDraw);
            }
        }
        fill(0);
        noStroke();
    }

    public void draw() {
        background(128);
        fill(0);
        noStroke();
        if (aRecStarted) {
            bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            // After we read the data from the AudioRecord object, we loop
            // through
            // and translate it from short values to double values. We can't do
            // this
            // directly by casting, as the values expected should be between
            // -1.0 and 1.0
            // rather than the full range. Dividing the short by 32768.0 will do
            // that,
            // as that value is the maximum value of short.
            volume = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < bufferReadResult; i++) {
                fftRealArray[i] = (float) buffer[i] / Short.MAX_VALUE;// 32768.0;
                volume += Math.abs(fftRealArray[i]);
            }
            volume = (float) Math.log10(volume / bufferReadResult);

            // apply windowing
            for (int i = 0; i < bufferReadResult / 2; ++i) {
                // Calculate & apply window symmetrically around center point
                // Hanning (raised cosine) window
                float winval = (float) (0.5f + 0.5f * Math.cos(Math.PI
                        * (float) i / (float) (bufferReadResult / 2)));
                if (i > bufferReadResult / 2)
                    winval = 0;
                fftRealArray[bufferReadResult / 2 + i] *= winval;
                fftRealArray[bufferReadResult / 2 - i] *= winval;
            }
            // zero out first point (not touched by odd-length window)
            fftRealArray[0] = 0;
            fft.forward(fftRealArray);

            //
            fill(255);
            stroke(100);
            pushMatrix();
            rotate(radians(90));
            translate(drawBaseLine - 3, 0);
            textAlign(LEFT, CENTER);
            for (float freq = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE / 2 - 1; freq > 0.0f; freq -= 150.0f) {
                int y = -(int) (fft.freqToIndex(freq) * drawScaleW); // which
                                                                        // bin
                                                                        // holds
                                                                        // this
                                                                        // frequency?
                line(-displayHeight, y, 0, y); // add tick mark
                text(Math.round(freq) + " Hz", 10, y); // add text label
            }
            popMatrix();
            noStroke();

            float lastVal = 0;
            float val = 0;
            float maxVal = 0; // index of the bin with highest value
            int maxValIndex = 0; // index of the bin with highest value
            for (int i = 0; i < fft.specSize(); i++) {
                val += fft.getBand(i);
                if (i % drawStepW == 0) {
                    val /= drawStepW; // average volume value
                    int prev_i = i - drawStepW;
                    stroke(255);
                    // draw the line for frequency band i, scaling it up a bit
                    // so we can see it
                    line(prev_i * drawScaleW, drawBaseLine,
                            prev_i * drawScaleW, drawBaseLine - lastVal
                                    * drawScaleH);

                    if (val - lastVal > PEAK_THRESH) {
                        stroke(255, 0, 0);
                        fill(255, 128, 128);
                        ellipse(i * drawScaleW,
                                drawBaseLine - val * drawScaleH, 20, 20);
                        stroke(255);
                        fill(255);
                        if (val > maxVal) {
                            maxVal = val;
                            maxValIndex = i;
                        }
                    }
                    line(prev_i * drawScaleW, drawBaseLine - lastVal
                            * drawScaleH, i * drawScaleW, drawBaseLine - val
                            * drawScaleH);
                    lastVal = val;
                    val = 0;
                }
            }
            if (maxValIndex - drawStepW > 0) {
                fill(255, 0, 0);
                ellipse(maxValIndex * drawScaleW, drawBaseLine - maxVal
                        * drawScaleH, 20, 20);
                fill(0, 0, 255);
                text(" " + fft.indexToFreq(maxValIndex - drawStepW / 2) + "Hz",
                        25 + maxValIndex * drawScaleW, drawBaseLine - maxVal
                                * drawScaleH);
            }
            fill(255);
            pushMatrix();
            translate(displayWidth / 2, drawBaseLine);
            text("buffer readed: " + bufferReadResult, 20, 80);
            text("fft spec size: " + fft.specSize(), 20, 100);
            text("volume: " + volume, 20, 120);
            popMatrix();
        } else {
            fill(255, 0, 0);
            text("AUDIO RECORD NOT INITIALIZED!!!", 100, height / 2);
        }
        fill(255);
        pushMatrix();
        translate(0, drawBaseLine);
        text("sample rate: " + RECORDER_SAMPLERATE + " Hz", 20, 80);
        text("displaying freq: 0 Hz  to  " + maxFreqToDraw + " Hz", 20, 100);
        text("buffer size: " + bufferSize, 20, 120);
        popMatrix();
    }

    public void stop() {
        audioRecord.stop();
        audioRecord.release();
    }

    public int sketchWidth() {
        return displayWidth;
    }

    public int sketchHeight() {
        return displayHeight;
    }}
```

And for fft I am using this class.
http://code.compartmental.net/minim/javadoc/ddf/minim/analysis/package-summary.html

I have 2 problems:

1. when I run in emulator, it works fine, but if I run in device I got error. Can anyone give me sugestion?
2. is this code return amplitude in the vertical line?

Comment: You get an error. Fine. **What** error ?

Comment: the error is like this
FATAL EXCEPTION: Animation Thread
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1024; index=1024
 at processing.test.android_fft_minim.android_fft_minim.draw(android_fft_minim.java:144)
 at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(Unknown Source)
 at processing.core.PGraphicsAndroid2D.requestDraw(Unknown Source)
 at processing.core.PApplet.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Comment: Are you sure that error matches this code? You haven't inserted or deleted lines or anything? That line number is a comment. I'm not an android programmer, but that seems weird to me.

Comment: i'm forget. when i post this code. i remove some line. sorry.

Comment: the error is in this line "
for (int i = 0; i < bufferReadResult; i++) {
                fftRealArray[i] = (float) buffer[i] / Short.MAX_VALUE;// 32768.0;
                volume += Math.abs(fftRealArray[i]);
            }
"

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?
It looks like instead of `bufferReadResult`, you should use `buffer.length`